# invoke iexplore.exe in already launched instance using ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sdk

I used `ShellExecuteEx` to call `iexplore.exe`, Whenever I start the application a new instance of internet explorer is created irrespective of, internet explorer already opened or not.

I want to change this, if already an instance of the Internet explorer is there, I need to open a new tab in that instance with the address I am passing to the `ShExecInfo.lpParameters`, thus without creating a new window. Is there a way to do this? Please advice..

UPADATE:
In the below answer I have a problem, when I set the lpFile parameter as "iexplore.exe" and lpParameters as "www.google.com", two windows get opened. If I ignore lpfile parameter, then the below code opens default browsers in some machine. I want only internet explorer to get opened. please help..

```
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) { 


 ShellExecute(0,L"open",L"iexplore.exe", L"http://www.google.com",0,SW_SHOWDEFAULT );       


 ShellExecute(0,L"open", L"iexplore.exe", L"http://www.yahoo.com",0,SW_SHOWDEFAULT );        

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is there any perticular reason you want to ignore the users configuration on where to open new tabs?

Comment: Or even, what browser they're using??

Comment: @Deanna I want the user to use only internet explorer..

Comment: I'm sorry but unless you're the network admin for corporate computers, that is not your decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works with `ShellExecute`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ShellExecute(0,L"open",L"http://www.google.com",0,0,SW_SHOWDEFAULT );   
    ShellExecute(0,L"open",L"http://www.yahoo.com",0,0,SW_SHOWDEFAULT );    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want the same to happen in ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: ShellExecuteEx uses Component Object Model, and you cant create new tab with some thing using CoInitializeEx.

Comment: Hi, I have an issue here, when I set the lpFile parameter as "iexplore.exe" and lpParameters parameter as "www.google.com", two windows got opened. If I ignore lpfile parameter, then the above code opens default browsers in some machine. I want only explorer to get opened. please help..

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I need for both the versions of the windows. And it should support for internet explorer starting from version 6. If the older versions like ie6 doenst support multi-tabbing, with out throwing any error the program should open in new window..

Comment: Do I want to compile in C++ compiler? I am geting errors in gcc compiler. Isnt it a C code?

Comment: [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'CoCreateInstance' 
objbase.h expected 'const struct IID * const' but argument is of type 'CLSID' 
[Error] incompatible type for argument 4 of 'CoCreateInstance' 
objbase.h expected 'const struct IID * const' but argument is of type 'IID' 
[Error] 'IWebBrowser2' has no member named 'put_Visible' 
[Error] 'navOpenInNewTab' undeclared (first use in this function)  
[Error] 'IWebBrowser2' has no member named 'Navigate2' 
[Error] 'IWebBrowser2' has no member named 'Release'